# line 66, in <module> c=menu() File "System-3.py", line 13, in menu StudentDetails() NameError: global name 'StudentDetails' is not defined

Tags: python

courses = ['Python Programming','Data Mining and Machine learning Course','Visual Analytics Course','Text Analytics Course']

def menu():                                                     #function for main menu
print("1. ADMINISTRATIVE MENU")
print("2. COURSE DETAILS")
print("3. STUDENT DETAILS")`enter code here`
print("4. EXIT")
c=int(input("Enter your choice "))

```
if c==2:
    diplomaProgramme()
elif c==3:
    StudentDetails()
elif c==1 :
    menu()
```

class diplomaProgramme():

```
  def __init__(self):
    query = int(input('Please fill the required input\
                  \nIf To add a course Press 1\
                      \nIf To Remove a course Press 2\
                          \nIf To quit a the Program Press 3\
                              \nEnter your choice: '))
    if query == 1:
        self.addCourse()
    elif query == 2:
        self.removeCourse()
    else:
        menu()
  def addCourse (self):
     course = input('Enter the course you want to add: ')
     courses.append(course)
     print('The course has been sucessfully added!')
     print('The following are all the courses: ', courses)
     q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
               \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press1\
                   \nIf you want to remove a course press 2\
                       \nEnter your choice: '))
     if q == 2:
         self.removeCourse()
     if q == 1:
         diplomaProgramme()
     else:
        menu()
    
  def removeCourse(self):  

    print('Thr Following are all the courses: ', courses)
    dcourse = input('which course do you want to remove? ')
    if dcourse in courses:
        courses.remove(dcourse)
    else:
        print('The course entered is not offered by the institute')
        
    q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
              \nIf to go back to previous menu Press 1\
                  \nIf you want to exit the program Press 2\
                      \nEnter your choice: '))
    if q == 1:
        pass 
    else:
        menu()
       c="y"
       while c=="y":
       c=menu()
       if c==3:
    class StudentDetails():
        
        def student_info(self):
            student=[]
            student = input('Enter the student name you want to add: ')
            unique_id = input('Enter the unique id: ')
            signed_up_courses = input('Enter the course name enrolled: ')
            assignment_status = input('Assignment Status: ')
            student.append(student)
            print('The student has been sucessfully added!')
            print('The following are all the students: ', student)
            q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
                           \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press1\
                             \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press2\
                               \nIf you want to remove a student press3\
                                 \nEnter your choice: '))
            if q == 1:
                self.student_info()
            if q == 2:
                self.student_info()
            if q == 3:
                self.removestudent()
            else:
                quit()
    
            print("Name : "+str(self.name))
            print("Unique ID : "+str(self.unique_id))
            print("Courses Taken : "+str(self.signed_up_courses))
            print("Grades : "+str(self.assignment_status))
            print("--------------------")

        def removestudent(self):
            print('Thr Following are all the students: ', student)
            dname = input('which student do you want to remove? ')
            if dname in student:
                 name.remove(dname)
            else:
                print('The sudent is not in the institute')
                q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
                               \nIf to go back to previous menu Press 1\
                                 \nIf you want to exit the program Press 2\
                                   \nEnter your choice: '))
                if q == 1:
                    pass 
                else:
                    quit()
```

Comment: Indentation *means something* in Python.  You have `class StudentDetails` indented such that it is defined only within the `removeCourse()` method, and cannot be used anywhere else in your program.

Comment: can you solve the question and post the snippet of the changes made

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and fixed the error mentioned by you. There was a mistake in indentation. Apart from that I have also corrected few other errors while solving the first one. Here is the code.

#Start of the program

```
courses = ['Python Programming','Data Mining and Machine learning Course','Visual Analytics Course','Text Analytics Course']

def menu():
    print("1. ADMINISTRATIVE MENU")
    print("2. COURSE DETAILS")
    print("3. STUDENT DETAILS")
    print("4. EXIT")


class diplomaProgramme():
    def __init__(self):
        query = int(input('Please fill the required input\
                  \nIf To add a course Press 1\
                      \nIf To Remove a course Press 2\
                          \nIf To quit a the Program Press 3\
                              \nEnter your choice: '))
        if query == 1:
            self.addCourse()
        elif query == 2:
            self.removeCourse()
        else:
            menu()
    def addCourse (self):
        course = input('Enter the course you want to add: ')
        courses.append(course)
        print('The course has been sucessfully added!')
        print('The following are all the courses: ', courses)
        q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
               \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press1\
                   \nIf you want to remove a course press 2\
                       \nEnter your choice: '))
        if q == 2:
            self.removeCourse()
        if q == 1:
            diplomaProgramme()
        else:
            menu()
    def removeCourse(self):
        print('Thr Following are all the courses: ', courses)
        dcourse = input('which course do you want to remove? ')
        if dcourse in courses:
            courses.remove(dcourse)
        else:
            print('The course entered is not offered by the institute')
        q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
              \nIf to go back to previous menu Press 1\
                  \nIf you want to exit the program Press 2\
                      \nEnter your choice: '))
        if q == 1:
            pass
        else:
            menu()
            c="y"
            while c=="y":
                c=menu()
        #if c==3:
class StudentDetails():
    def __init__(self):
        student_list=[]
        student = input('Enter the student name you want to add: ')
        unique_id = input('Enter the unique id: ')
        signed_up_courses = input('Enter the course name enrolled: ')
        assignment_status = input('Assignment Status: ')
        student_list.append(student)
        print('The student has been sucessfully added!')
        print('The following are all the students: ', student_list)
        q = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
                           \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press1\
                             \nIf  to go back to previous menu Press2\
                               \nIf you want to remove a student press3\
                                 \nEnter your choice: '))
        if q == 1:
            self.__init__()
        if q == 2:
            self.__init__()
        if q == 3:
            print('The Following are all the students: ', student_list)
            dname = input('which student do you want to remove? ')
            if dname in student_list:
                student_list.remove(dname)
            else:
                print('The sudent is not in the institute')
            q1 = int(input('Please decide what you want to do next?\
                               \nIf to go back to previous menu Press 1\
                                 \nIf you want to exit the program Press 2\
                                   \nEnter your choice: '))
            if q1 == 1:
                pass
            else:
                quit()
        else:
            quit()
        
menu()
c=int(input("Enter your choice "))
if c==2:
    diplomaProgramme()
elif c==3:
    StudentDetails()
elif c==1 :
    menu()
```